# If I don't publish my app and watch ads in that app would it be considered as invalid clicks?

Tags: android, admob, ads

I have built an android app but I didn't publish it on play store. I have ads in my app so if I distribute that app among my friends and they watch those ads. Would it be considered as invalid clicks?

Comment: What would be the point of showing ads if it is only for your friends?

Comment: Not only for friends but I and my friends started a student football tournament so I wanted to give other students a great experience about our tournament but I don't have developer account

Answer (score 0):

Yeah these are invalid clicks and Google may suspend your Admob account due to this.
https://support.google.com/admob/answer/2753860?hl=en

Comment: What if I publish it through someone else's account after 10 to 15 days lets say. Would these still be invalid clicks?

Comment: After publishing clicks would be valid but avoid too much clicks, one of my friends account had suspended due to this